# Why does the arcpy module not have a code hint function in pycharm

Tags: python

There is a clear code prompt function in arcgis pro, such as typing arcpy. There will be a lot of prompts later, but when the same python file is put into pycharm, nothing happens.

I tried clearing the pycharm index buffer, restarting pycharm, and using environment variables, but none of them worked.

Comment: The prompt displayed on my side is "Cannot find the reference 'management' in '__init__.py' ", and only the .py file in arcpy cannot be automatically prompted by the code, and the rest are automatically prompted.

Comment: It seems that pycharm currently prompts the old version of arcpy syntax, such as "arcpy.da.SearchCursor" cannot be automatically prompted, but it can prompt "arcpy.SearchCursor"